# WebChat programmatic post activity not working - no message sent on button click

Tags: botframework

I am following these 2 samples:

1. [Webchat with react](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/03.a.host-with-react)
2. [Programmatic post activity](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/15.c.programmatic-post-activity)

My bot is working ok. I can send and process activities via directline. My test helpButton logs ok, but there is no actual 'help' message sent when I click the button like in the sample.

```js
var mainBotConnection;

const { createStore, ReactWebChat } = window.WebChat;
const { createProvider } = window.ReactRedux;
const Provider = createProvider('webchat');
const Store = createStore();

// get a token
const RequestToken = async (user) => {
    ...
};

(async function () {
   RequestToken(agent)
        .then(token => {

            //init main chat bot
            mainBotConnection = window.WebChat.createDirectLine({token: token});

            ...

            //grab mainbot placeholder and put it on screen
            window.ReactDOM.render(
                <Provider store={Store}>
                    <ReactWebChat
                        directLine={mainBotConnection}
                        storeKey='webchat'
                        userID={user.id}
                        username={user.name}
                        styleOptions={mainBotStyleOptions}
                    />
                </Provider>,
                document.getElementById('webchat'));

            // this message does not appear
            Store.dispatch({
                type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_MESSAGE',
                payload: { text: 'StartUp hello!' }
            });
        });
   
    // test button
    document.querySelector('#helpButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
        // this is successfully logged 
        console.log(`help button clicked`);
        
        // 'help' text does not appear in bot
        Store.dispatch({
            type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_MESSAGE',
            payload: { text: 'help' }
        });
        
        // this is also successfully logged 
        console.log(Store);
    });

    document.querySelector('#webchat').focus();
})().catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: adding your full html would be a lot better... here we don't see your button declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `store={Store}` to your `ReactWebChat` component:

```html
[...]
<Provider store={Store}>
    <ReactWebChat
        directLine={mainBotConnection}
        storeKey='webchat'
        userID={user.id}
        username={user.name}
        styleOptions={mainBotStyleOptions}
        store={Store} // ADD THIS PART
    />
</Provider>,
[...]
```

That being said, without the rest of your code, I wasn't able to test this exactly. Instead, I started up the [React with Redux Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/14.customization-piping-to-redux). If I removed `store={Store}`, it didn't work, but if I left it in there, it worked just fine and sent both the welcome and help messages. You may also need: `<Provider store={ store } key='webchat'>`, but like I said, I wasn't able to test your exact code.

Comment: That was exactly it. I thought `Provider store={Store}` covered linking the store to the bot since that's the only time it was specified in the sample. Thanks!